# Update multiple columns with same random value in a query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

This SQL query

```
UPDATE post
SET random = FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) *15 ),
    value = FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) *15 )
```

returns two different values for columns '`random`' and ' `value`'.

Is it possible to update the two columns in one query with an identical random value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need two columns to store same random value ? A single column should have been enough!

However, MySQL allows the following non-SQL-Standard-Compliant [behaviour](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html):

> If you access a column from the table to be updated in an expression,
>   UPDATE uses the current value of the column. For example, the
>   following statement sets col1 to one more than its current value:
>
> ```
> UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1;
> ```
>
> The second assignment in the following statement sets col2 to the
>   current (updated) col1 value, not the original col1 value. The result
>   is that col1 and col2 have the same value. This behavior differs from
>   standard SQL.
>
> ```
> UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1, col2 = col1;
> ```

So, you can try the following:

```
UPDATE post
SET random = FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) *15 ),
    value = random
```